# Send MiniDump to Microsoft after Recovering from OS Blue Screen

Tags: windows-7

Occasionally I encountered Blue Screen of Death on my Windows 7 32 bit ( Yes, windows 7!). I believe that this is software error, and from Event Viewer I can see when and what the error is. This is a sample of such a report:

> The computer has rebooted from a
>   bugcheck.  The bugcheck was:
>   0x0000004e (0x00000099, 0x0008737d,
>   0x00000002, 0x00089e37). A dump was
>   saved in: C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP.
>   Report Id: 111310-25209-01.

I think it's worthwhile to send this kind of bug report and dumps to Microsoft. But I don't see any "Send me" button at event viewer. How to send minidump generated from crash to Microsoft, after I have recovered from OS Blue Screen of Death?

Comment: Any options regarding what you are looking for can be found here.
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System\Advanced System Settings/Advanced  Under Startup and recovery Press Settings now you find settings for "Write Debug Information. It seems that there is no such thing as report bug, you can only choose to write or not write debug info. to disc.

Comment: If you wish, you can zip and upload the minidump file(s) to a file hosting site of your choice, post the link here and I can download and attempt to analyze the file for you.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559014%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Bug Check 0x4E: PFN_LIST_CORRUPT

Parameter 1: 0x99;  Page frame number; Current page state;  0;  A page table entry (PTE) or PFN is corrupted.

Cause
This error is typically caused by a driver passing a bad memory descriptor list. For example, the driver might have called MmUnlockPages twice with the same list.

---

My advice is to check your RAM (memory). My experience says that you might have a hardware problem. Insert W7 DVD on boot and select Memory Check.

Answer (score -1):

The appropriate process is documented here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/129845

Comment: Link appears to be broken.